# MySQL: How to select where column A not in column B?

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have the following table named FRUITSALAD:

```
| ID | FRUIT  | SALAD        |
|----|--------|--------------|
| 1  | apple  | apple,orange |
| 2  | orange | pear,banana  |
| 3  | banana | apple        |
| 4  | grape  | apple,grape  |
| 5  | pear   |              |
| 6  |        | apple,pear   |
```

NOTE: The SALAD column contains any number of comma-separated fruits.

How can I select ID where FRUIT is not in SALAD? (***rows 2, 3, 5 / not row 6***)

My first thought was to try this, but it returned all rows where fruit exists:

```
SELECT id FROM fruitsalad WHERE fruit NOT IN (salad)
```

I'm hoping to do this without a join or nested subquery if possible, but I'd appreciate any suggestion that gets it done. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, you can do this using `find_in_set()`:

```
select id
from fruitsalad
where find_in_set(fruit, salad) = 0;
```

To handle row 6, you might need:

```
select id
from fruitsalad
where find_in_set(fruit, salad) = 0 and
      fruit is not null and fruit <> '';
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick response! I didn't know about find_in_set. I'll try that and post back my results. I'm also not familiar with "<> ''". What does that bit do?

Comment: @JoshR . . . `<>` is the ANSI standards for `!=` (not equals).

Comment: Perfect! Thanks again, Gordon. FYI, the first version is sufficient when FRUIT is either defined or null and when SALAD is either defined or blank. Possibly under other circumstances as well, but those are mine. Still curious about the `<> ''` part in the second version.

Comment: Oh, got it! Is one better than the other? I always use !=.

Comment: @JoshR . . . I prefer `<>` for SQL, because that is the original and standard form.  Some databases don't support `!=`.